# The corner cases to generate a Pascal's Triangle

Tags: python, algorithm

I am taking efforts to solve  problem [Pascal's Triangle - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/pascals-triangle/)

> Given a non-negative integer *numRows*, generate the first *numRows* of Pascal's triangle.
>
> In Pascal's triangle, each number is the sum of the two numbers directly above it.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> Input: 5
> Output:
> [
>      [1],
>     [1,1],
>    [1,2,1],
>   [1,3,3,1],
>  [1,4,6,4,1]
> ]
> ```

My solution:

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.res = [[]]
    def generate(self, numRows: int) -> 'List[List[int]]':
        #base case 
        if numRows == None: return None 
        if numRows == 0: return None
        pt = []
        for i in range(1, numRows+1):
            row = [1] * i
            pt.append(row)
        if numRows <=2: return pt

        #recur relations 
        for i in range(2, numRows): #start from row  3
            for j in range(1, len(pt[i])-1):#column, 
                #logging.debug(f"i:{i}, i-1:{i-1}, j:{j}, j-1:{j-1}")
                pt[i][j] = pt[i-1][j-1] + pt[i-1][j]
        return pt
```

Unfortunately, fail to pass leetcodes's Testcase:

> numRows = 0, expected [] but output None.

I once think thorough beforehand, if numRows is 0, it means that  row does not exist, rather than there exits one row but with zero element.

numRow == 0 is the same as numRow = None which differ from  my_salary = 0 (free job)and my_salary ==None (no job)

Put it in a clear way, the salary can be negative, but cannot get a negative row  at the current technologies when we should took years to render a picture a back hole.

How could  understand the default setting `numRows = 0`but get `[]`

Comment: What is your question? [] indicates a triangle with no rows. [[]] would be a triangle with one empty row.

Comment: oh,yes, thank you. @andrew.punnett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, there is an outer list that surrounds all inner lists (rows) of numbers. This outer list will always be there, even if there are no rows. It's always a list with `numRows` elements, so if `numRows == 0`, it's a list with 0 elements.

Basically just remove both of your `if numRows ==` checks at the beginning and it should pass the test case.